# RichTextBox input is very laggy

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, .net-4.5

I've got a `RichTextBox`, with a very small amount of text in (less than 100 characters including line endings). I have one event (`TextChanged` with an empty body), no styles, and the window is pretty simple.

```
<Window x:Class="W.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="FileTabControl">
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <RichTextBox AcceptsReturn="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="SampleTextBox">
                <RichTextBox.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                    </Style>
                </RichTextBox.Resources>
            </RichTextBox>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

That's it.

But when I type code into the RichTextBox, it feels very laggy and stuttery. I've read about a lot of other people with performance issues with WPF's RTB in pretty similar circumstances, but none of them seem to have found a solution.

Just for a note, I could use something like AvalonEdit, but I failed to parse whether or not the LGPL means it's unusable in commercial projects, and I also require syntax highlighting and stuff based on unmanaged code, rather than defining a syntax highlight thingy.

Comment: Have you tried setting a lower `UndoLimit` on the `RichTextBox`, I have found on `TextBoxes` this improves input performance a LOT as I think the default is `int.MaxValue`, maybe worth a try `<RichTextBox UndoLimit="50" />` as a test.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did most assuredly not solve the issue.

Comment: I tested and got zero lag.  Where are you assigning the text changed event.  And why an empty event?  Think you have something else going on.

Comment: @Blam: It had things in which I subsequently commented out. I assign it in the constructor of my Window subclass. I know that it doesn't repro on all systems.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `RichtTextBox` from Windows Forms it works faster. But this is maybe not the most beautiful solution.